# How can I tell Maven to add the dependencies of my war on the test classpath?

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I have built a set of servlets and bundled them all in a WAR.
I have built a client library and bundled all its classes in a JAR.

I would like to test the client library against the WAR. I tried this :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>the-war-of-myproject</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to add a WAR as a dependency in a pom.xml.
How should I do ?

**Eclipse Indigo**
**JDK 6**
**Maven 3**

**EDIT:**
Based on wemu's comment, I have decided to move the classes required by both the WAR and the JAR into a common dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what tests you need to run from your client.jar to the server.war file

You could create a 3rd project, add both client.jar and server.war as a dependency and use the war packageing too for this test-module. This would overlay the war into your test-war module.

If you dont need the war file but dependencies of it (service layer classes) i would only include those for testing.